# Synchronous” methods(actions) in my Asynchronous controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to implement async method in MVC4 in Visual studio 2010. Since Iam using .net framework 4.0 I can’t use “async/await” methods in my controller. So im planning to  derive my controller from AsyncController and implement async actions.

The question is can I use “Synchronous” methods(actions) in my Asynchronous controller. Since in the same controller I have synchronous actions already there. Is there any best practices? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by "synchronous", you mean "blocking".

You could call synchronous methods just fine. Obviously, synchronous/blocking code will not give you the scalability benefits of asynchronous code.

If you want the scalability benefits, you'll need to rewrite all your blocking methods to be asynchronous. Please note that this is non-trivial; paying for VS2013 and upgrading to .NET 4.5 is a *lot* less work and a *lot* less expensive (once you consider developer time as an expense).

Comment: Hi Stephen, Thanks for the info and it is much usefull. Actually my question is can i have synchronous methods in a controller which is inherited from 'asynccontroller' class. I found answer from MSDN that i can have synchronous methods in async controller. So im closing this question.